# how to get intergers from pyodbc's fetch?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to use the `update` statement, but my database won't accept `(int, )` only int.

```
import pyodbc
connect_data = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
    r'DBQ=C:\filename.accdb;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connect_data)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute('select ID from WeatherAnalisis')
weathertable = crsr.fetchmany(5)
for rowcount in weathertable:
    timeCET = timeCET + timeincrement
    print (rowcount)
    sql = "UPDATE WeatherAnalisis SET Time_UTC = ? WHERE ID = ?"
    crsr.execute(sql, timeCET, rowcount)
    cnxn.commit()
>>>>
(1, )
crsr.execute(sql, timeCET, rowcount)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type  (67) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

This seems to be because the `rowcount` is in the `(int, )` format instead of `int`
now my question is: How do I get it to give me just the interger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.fetchmamy()` returns a list of pyodbc `Row` objects. A `Row` object behaves like a tuple, so if it only contains one column you can extract it as a scalar value like so:

```py
for row in weathertable:
    rowcount = row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out myself

```py
rowiercount = str(rowcount)
rowiercount.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", ""))
```

It most likely isn't effectient, but it seems to do the job
I will not yet mark this as solved because if someone else has this issue to, there probably is a better way to do this.